# Selectsinglenode in IXMLDOMElement?

Tags: selectsinglenode, ixmldomelement

can i perform select single node from IXMLDOMElement ,if its possible give me one example for that using MSXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what language?  To solve what problem?

For what it's worth, the MSDN documentation for IXMLDOMElement::selectSingleNode can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(VS.85).aspx), and includes samples in a few different languages.